# national characters in Oracle

Tags: oracle, char, oracle19c, nvarchar

we are using Oracle 19c
there are setting in nls_database_parameters

nls_nchar_characterset is UTF8
nls_charchterset is WE8ISO8859P15

I have a table with one column of varchar2 and another column of nvarchar2

I try to insert in both column the same letter,non english ,for example ş and it is not wotking but if I try another non english letter in my language like ž then is is working in both columns. Another colleagues of mine can not insert any letter correctly using the same database user. I don't understand this behavior,what defines what you can insert as national character?

we receive a big list of different cities in different languages. What is the best way to insert all of them correctly?

Comment: Using the national character set is not really state of the art anymore. Use UTF-8 (i.e. `AL32UTF8`) as character set. Anyway, how do you insert the data? Which application do you use?

Comment: Can you post the hexdumps of the characters dump(<column>,16)?

Comment: but the parameter is set to UTF-8. simple insert statement  in sql developer. insert inyo table values ....